# How to deploy a .war file AKS using Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am new to Azure Devops and would request your suggestions to complete my CICD process with AzureDevops

We need to do following process using azure Devops CICD

1) we are using Azure repo as our VS and we have 2 repos right now.  one is 'DEV" repo for our developers to commit the java codes and anoither is "Admin" repo where we are keeping our docker files and Kubernetes deployment files.

2) We need to use maven build to iniate a build when developer commits the code to "Dev Repo" and package it to a .war file (which is need to kept in Artifactory for reference)

3) We have a docker file for creating the Tomcat docker image with the .war file created from above step. Once the image is created it should send to ACR with proper naming convention

4) We have a kubernetes deployment file to deploy in AKS with this created image. this should be automated when the build and image push is done from the previous job.

Could you please guide me here with proper suggestions for each steps.. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: In your second demand, did you want to pack the changes which commit to the repos as a .war file? Or pack the build pipeline result ?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT i hope its better to keep the war file versioned in Azure artifatory, thats why we put like this. or please suggest some other idea.

Comment: Got that, just confusing for what do you want to pack into the war file? All of the code? Or the build result about the commit change? This is very important to know which task or step you should do.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT yes, we want to package the entire code developed by the developers using maven and the package should be kept in azure artifacts. again we have to build a tomcat image with that .war file  and from there to ACR, and from ACR to AKS